# Adding comments/notes to windows10 files/folders

Tags: windows-10, productivity

I want to find an tool that would let me assign comments/notes to (any) files/folders. Preferably it can integrate itself to the right click menu and isn't janky (for example, if it creates a new file that I need to keep together with the original file, no thanks). Is there such an app that would allow me to Right Click->Notes and write down a few things about the file? I dont want it to make a separate file or clutter anything. If it is searchable through windows, would be amazing.

Comment: You might find something that uses the "alternate data streams" of the file to store the extra information. (Look at the `\R` option to the `dir` command.)  This is a feature of NTFS that allows a file to have additional contents that are normally not visible.

Comment: Don't have anything specific in mind, but there is a growing industry standard called file-system labeling, try searching for that

Answer (score 1):

NTFS the Windows file-system has the ability to store multiple "[alternate data streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_stream_(ADS))" with each file. Effectively a list of files that are coupled to a regular file and that don't get lost as long as you copy/move the file using Windows tools that are alternate data stream aware.

There is a shell-extension named "File Metadata" that uses alternate data streams to store and edit notes and other meta data:

https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta/wiki/What-you-see

I have not tried it myself, but it seems to be exactly what you are looking for (at least for files).

Comment: finger's crossed