# Any software that can be used to easily add comments to any folder and file within Windows File explorer?

Tags: windows-10, file

Is there any software that can be used to add comments to any folder and file type within the Windows file explorer? Using the built in functionality of Windows, very few of my file types seem to allow comments and I cannot add comment to folders. The process also takes far too long, so I am looking for something that would allow me to right click and add a comment for example.

I found this answer [Adding comments/notes to windows10 files/folders](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80541/adding-comments-notes-to-windows10-files-folders) but it seems to only apply to files. I need a solution that works for both folders and files

Answer (score 0):

For folders, use StyleFolder (free). It will let you write some words that can then be seen in the 'comments' column. (You may have to refresh)

Comment: Please provide a summary of its attributes and a link to the website, in your answer.